# Unescaping HTML entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-escape-characters

I fetch JSON from Reddit API, parse the JSON, and loop through the results in my view. A JSON field contains HTML tags to embed a video. I'm trying to print this string directly on my view, embedding the video.

However, Rails escapes the HTML, and I see my `iframe` tags printed verbatim on the screen. I'm trying the `raw` and `html_safe` methods, and neither is working. Here's what I've tried in my view ERB file:

```
<% reddit = ApiCallController.new %>
<% reddit.index['data']['children'].each do |child| %>
   <%= child['data']['title'] %> <br>
   <%= child['data']['media_embed']['content'].html_safe %> <br>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% reddit = ApiCallController.new %>
<% reddit.index['data']['children'].each do |child| %>
    <%= child['data']['title'] %> <br>
    <%= raw child['data']['media_embed']['content'] %> <br>
<% end %>
```

I can work around this, but I'd like to figure out how to unescape HTML entities.

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe data arrives escaped?

Comment: Thank you. I feel so stupid, but that's exactly what it was.

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself, the best place for a bug to hide is right out in the open.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergio Tulentsev pointed out, the string was arriving escaped and I seemed to overlook that. I ran an HTMLEntities decode on it and it worked as I expected.